# Organize stored procedures, views, functions etc with sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, code-organization

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to work with a database. I'm only a .Net developer with limited experience in managing sql server, I'm far from a real DBA.  In next few days, the number of stored procedures are going to increase very much. Also more views and functions will be created.

Are there any way to organize this elements in folders? I don't want to have dozens of SP under the same folder. It will be a pain to maintain.

Of course, I know that using a name convention will help me, but are there anything more that I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: This has been an ongoing disappointment for me that Microsoft, after all these years, STILL hasn't provided a way to organize stored procs. And though schemas can be used somewhat for organizing, they're very crude for this purpose and you still end up having to wade through 100s of objects instead of being able to collapse them down into folders you can quickly navigate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, SSMS doesn't allow you to group schema objects in folders. Your best bet would be to use SQL Server Schema's to organize your objects. Each schema would represent an area of functionality such as 'Customer', 'Security', 'Master' etc. This is a great way to organize your objects, and implement security.

Take a look at this SO thread on Schema's:
[What good are SQL Server schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529142/what-good-are-sql-server-schemas)