# What is dbo in dbo.Sometable

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In my local or on a dedicated server, when i create a table i see the table name as follows:

```
dbo.Foo
```

As i was given a database account from some plesk environment, the tables which were created get the name :

```
mydbuser.Foo
```

How does prefix matter for my code? or If i create a table/ restore one from my backup, should i expect weird results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824425/sql-server-tables-named-with-dbo-schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbo is the default schema that is assigned to a table when you create a table and don't assign a schema explicitly. A database schema is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. You can read more about schemas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema)

> How does prefix matter for my code?

If you don't specify schema in the code, then it will take dbo as default. Though if you have a table with schema other than dbo, then you will have to specify in your code as well, otherwise it won't execute.

> If i create a table/ restore one from my backup, should i expect weird results?

Schemas are not evil. If you specify them correctly, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**dbo**

It is schema.  If no default schema is defined for a user account, SQL Server will assume dbo is the default schema.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> SQL Server 2005 introduced the concept of database schemas and the
> separation between database objects and ownership by users. An object
> owned by a database user is no longer tied to that user. The object
> now belongs to a schema – a container that can hold many database
> objects. The schema owner may own one or many schemas. This concept
> creates opportunities to expose database objects within a database for
> consumption yet protect them from modification, direct access using
> poor query techniques, or removal by users other than the owner.

To create your own Schema, you can use following script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [EnterSchemaNameHere] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
```

You can use them to logically group your tables, for example by creating a schama for "Financial" information and another for "Personal" data. Your tables would then display as:

Financial.Foo

Personal.Foo