# Relationship between schema and database instance

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2

I am confused about relationship between  schema  and database instance.
What is the difference between schema and İnstance in Oracle,Sql Server and DB2?

Answer (score 1):

How much you can view in essence.

It is very popular to just have separate databases for many thing with one used schema per datebase, but say I want to have these two databases (history and production for example) in one. I may want to have two users that have two different schema.

One for History to be able to access the history tables/functions/etc.
One for Production for the same reason.

Each of these will have their own schema, on one database instance.

Another topic about schemas, why they are beneficial: [What good are SQL Server schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529142/what-good-are-sql-server-schemas)

Pretty much the same question: [Difference between database and schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema)