# What is schema and database?

Tags: sql

What is the difference between schema and database? I have no knowledge other than running basic commands in sql such as `select`, `update`, `insert` and `delete`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between database and schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema)

Comment: i don't know what is the basics itself there it has been discussed about the difference only

Comment: Either that provided link, or a Google search.  This doesn't warrant yet another question.

Comment: There is no such thing called "database" in the SQL standard. The namespace "above" a schema is called a "catalog".

Answer (score 0):

A Database is a collection of organized data, while database schema describes the structure and organization of data in a database system. The database holds the records, fields and cells of data. The database schema describes how these fields and cells are structured and organized and what types of relationships are mapped between these entities. Understandably, the schema of a database keeps constant once created, while the actual data in the database tables may change all the time.

Comment: so what i understand from your answer is database is collection of data (what are the data's i save ) where as schema say how to store the data /

Comment: The term "schema" refers to the organization of data as a blueprint of how the database is constructed (divided into database tables in the case of relational databases).

Comment: The term schema also refers to a namespace that groups objects together