# How to use SQL Server View and Schema?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Based upon the thread:
[SQL Server View vs Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema)

I have created a schema named as Network in my SQL Server Database. The idea is to have logical group of sql views that will be part of this schema.

1. How to associate the sql view to the schema?
2. How to execute the view? Network.?
3. How to view the list of views created in a particular sql server schema?

Example of SQL Server View:

```
Create view v_Customer
as
Select * from Customer
```

Comment: To execute a sql server view binded to a schema: select * from Network.v_Customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object`(View) names in sql server has 4 part identifiers

```
ServerName.DatabaseName.schemaName.objectName
```

When you don't mention the servername and database name then the object will be created on database on which the connection is made.

When you don't mention the schema name while creating a object(view) it will be created on the default schema. Mostly it will be `dbo`

Just add `schema` name before the `View` name

```
Create view Network.v_Customer
as
Select * from Customer
```

To view the list of views created in a particular sql server schema

```
select * 
from sys.objects o
  JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
Where o.type = 'V'
and   s.name = 'schema_name'
```

The reason for not using `SCHEMA_NAME()` and joining `sys.schemas` is here

[Bad habits : Using (certain) metadata "helper" functions](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions/)

Comment: Great answer, but you left out question 3 which I would suggest just using sys.views

Comment: @AnthonyHancock - It is newly added when I answered it is not there :)