# Rails Multi tenant Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant

I am creating a multi-tenant rails app for different clubs. I'm using the apartment gem so it creates different databases for each club which has  more than 100 tables.  now i want to  take dump of one  tenant and import it to other club tenant

Comment: Looks like an intention. So what's your question?

Comment: How do you want us to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Apartment gem create different schema for different tenenats not databases. You can check difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema).

For your case you can copy record of one schema using below command:

```
pg_dump -U <username> -p <port> -n <source> <database name> >> <dump filename>
```

`source` is your schema name for source. It is your primary tenant which you want to copy.

`target` is you schema where you want copy all records.

Change your schema name in your new dump file by opening in any editor.

```
# edit the dump.file

CREATE SCHEMA <source>; => CREATE SCHEMA <target>;
ALTER SCHEMA <source> OWNER TO <username>; => ALTER SCHEMA <target> OWNER TO <username>;
```

Now restore new dump file.

```
psql -U <username> -p <port> -d <database> -f <dump filename>
```

You can copy data from one tenant to another tenanat by creating a rake task and switching tenants.

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!("one tenant")

# Retrive data that you want in a local object
# local_object = Model.all

Apartment::Tenant.switch!("second tenant")

# Save all data in second tenant from local_oject
# local_oject.each do |object|
#   object.save
# end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using this way but not saving in new tenant    
Apartment::Tenant.switch("tenant1")
        members= Member.all
        Apartment::Tenant.switch("tenant2")
        members.each do |member|
          begin
            member.save
            puts "migrating member.id"
          rescue=>e
            puts e
          end
        end
```

Comment: This is not an answer. May be add it to your question.

Comment: Is your new tenant properly created ? use switch! instead of switch in your rake task to make sure tenant exist.