# Is it good practice to use dots within table names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that, in MSSQL, sub-structures of a database like Views, Schemas and Tables can be referenced using object notation such as:

Database.Schema.Table.Column

Each of these objects I believe has their own properties.

I need to replicate the structure of an MSSQL DB in MySQL and I am unsure what is the best practice.

I am thinking about creating tables in MySQL with the following naming convention:

```
Database
|---SubStructureX.Table
|   |---Column_A
|   |---Column_B
|---SubStructureY.Table
|   |---Column_C
|   |---Column_D
|
|
```

Therefore a MySQL query could look like this:

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B FROM SubStructureX.Table
```

In short, "SubstructureX.Table" is just a table name that contains a dot. I would be doing this for ease of use during replication of the MSSQL structure. I don't care if the things before and after the dot are not objects in MySQL.

Is this good MySQL practice?

Comment: Are you planning to create `schemas` in `MSSQL` ?

Comment: The MSSQL database is created already and it contains Schemas and Views.  I am trying to replicate the structure in MySQL. I guess I could also ask does MySQL support Schemas and Views?, but I really have no use for those structures once I have the DB ported to MySQL. Let me know if that makes sense, I may not be getting the terminology correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL?  No, I would think that it's not good practice to use periods in table names at all.  I would think that it's very bad practice.  The dot is the reference operator in SQL.  That means if you want to refer to a column using fully qualified notation, you do so like this:

```
SELECT Table.Column_A ...
```

Or, with backtick quoting:

```
SELECT `Table`.`Column_A` ...
```

Now, imagine if your table is named `StructureX.Table`.  Just like with a space, you've got to quote that to escape it because you don't want MySQL to think the dot is an operator.  That means your SQL has to look like this:

```
SELECT `StructureX.Table`.Column_A ...
```

Or, with backtick quoting:

```
SELECT `StructureX.Table`.`Column_A` ...
```

Doesn't that look like a syntax error to you?  Like maybe it's supposed to be like this:

```
SELECT `StructureX`.`Table`.`Column_A` ...
```

This would be a nightmare to maintain and as a systems analyst I would hate any application or developer that inflicted this nomenclature on me.  It makes me want to claw my eyes out.

Microsoft SQL Server is different because it supports multiple schemas within a single database, while MySQL treats schema as a synonym for database.  In MS SQL Server, [schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529142/what-good-are-sql-server-schemas) are collections of objects, and you can use them to organize your tables, or apply security to tables as a group.  The default schema is `dbo`, which is why you see that one listed so often.  In MS SQL Server syntax, this:

```
SELECT [StructureX].[Table].[Column_A] ...
```

Means within the current database, the schema named `StructureX`, table named `Table`, and column name `Column_A`.  MS SQL Server actually supports a [four part name](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1095/sql-server-four-part-naming/), with the fourth part being the database:

```
SELECT [MyDatabase].[StructureX].[Table].[Column_A] ...
```

Here, `MyDatabase` is the database name.

That same style works in MySQL, except you have to remember that schema and database are synonymous.  So there, this:

```
SELECT `StructureX`.`Table`.`Column_A` ...
```

Would mean database `StructureX`, table `Table`, and column `Column_A`.

Comment: This is where I was trying to go. Instead of using the dot, would it be good practice to use an underscore in the table name? I'm assuming so, but just want to know the opinions of others. So in MSSQL I would have DB.Schema.Table and I could create tables in MySQL as DB --> Schema_Table, where "Schema_Table" is just a run-of-the-mill MySQL table.

Comment: @Charlie Yes, an underscore would be perfectly fine.  I work with several systems that use a short abbreviation for the area the table is related to at the start of the table (usually 2-4 characters) that help organize tables into groups.  It makes it *much* easier to find associated tables.

Answer (score 0):

I Can say yes:

But instead of using table name, make a table some alias like this,

> select **a.column1** from yourTable as **a**

Using table `alias` is a good practice.

Comment: The question is about the best practice for naming convention of MySQL tables, not querying tables. Therefore, using you query above as an example, would this be good practice: SELECT column1 FROM a.yourTable AS aTableAlias

Comment: Your question said using "dot(.)" as far as i know using "dot(.)" seems to be an aliases so with naming convention too. Its all up to you.

Comment: I meant to ask using periods (.) as part of a table name, such as This.Is.One.Table

Comment: I can say no. Its not a good practice. It could allocate some memory space of creating a long table name but not necessarily needed.