# Creating Table in SSMS (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I create a table using the interface with SSMS the table "prefix" automatically is set to

```
MyCompanyName\MyUserID.tableName.
```

However when I create a table with a query I am able to set the "prefix" to 
    dbo.tableName.

MY 2 questions are

```
 (1). What does this "prefix" mean?  
 (2). How do I set the "prefix" to dbo using the SSMS interface?
```

I've done some research but can't figure out whether it refers to the schema (which I don't know anything about) or the user.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

-Charlie

Comment: The "prefix" you are referring to is the [Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema) which allows you a number of extra features in SQL, like permissions to that specific schema, or allowing you to group tables together in a database, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What good are SQL Server schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529142/what-good-are-sql-server-schemas)

Comment: Thanks Jacob!  Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "prefix" is [schema name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql).

You can change it in SSMS in property page (press F4 to open):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's simply adding the schema name as a prefix.

Sorry, covered in other answers above - I was 30 secs too late.